# Can't Connect to Apache Server on LAN

Tags: apache, lan

I have a very simple LAN setup and am trying to connect to an Apache server running on the LAN. The server IP is 192.168.1.178. I'm trying to connect from a box on same LAN with IP of 192.168.1.161. Attempting to connect from browser results in error saying site is unreachable. I can ping the server and SSH into the server. But, telnet and curl result in no route to host errors.

Both boxes are set up with static IPs. DNS for static connection is 192.168.1.1. Both boxes are running Manjaro and no firewalls are turned on. Apache access logs show no attempt to connect and there are no errors in the Apache error logs.

I also set up a test python server (sudo python -m http.server 80) to try that. Attempting to curl to that server results in 'connection refused' error as opposed to 'no route to host' error for the Apache server.

Traceroute results are:

```
 traceroute 192.168.1.178                                                
traceroute to 192.168.1.178 (192.168.1.178), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  raptor (192.168.1.178)  0.434 ms !X  0.366 ms !X  0.400 ms !X
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that a firewall daemon was running, which was causing the problem. Disabling the firewall solved the issue.